# How to set dynamic properties on object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Dynamically I'm getting several objects having the following structure.

```
obj1 = {
   prop: 'one',
   key: 'string',
   value: 2
}

obj2 = {
   prop: 'one',
   key: 'diffString',
   value: 3
 }
```

Also, I have an object which I want to turn into this using received objects.

```
mainObject = {
   prop: {
     key1: value,
     key2: value
   }
}
```

I'm trying to use this

```
mainObject[obj.prop][obj.key] = obj.value;
```

But it gives me an error because at this point `mainObject` is just an empty object and it doesn't have `mainObject[obj.prop]`

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: `mainObject[obj.prop] = {}` first then `mainObject[obj.prop][obj.key] = obj.value;`

Comment: Your desired output doesn't use any of the property values from your input objects. Is that what you want, just to take the property names from the input? (If you actually want to use the values, e.g., "diffString" and 3, please [edit] the question to show an output example reflecting that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this is as follows:

```
// If no value for obj.prop exists, assign empty object
mainObject[obj.prop] = mainObject[obj.prop] || {}; 

// Assign value to obj.key of object at mainObject[obj.prop]
mainObject[obj.prop][obj.key] = obj.value;
```

This code is first ensuring that a valid value (object) exists at the key `obj.prop` on `mainObject`. If there is not valid object at key `obj.prop`, then a new empty object is assigned `{}`.

The `mainObject[obj.prop][obj.key] = obj.value` assignment can now be performed safely seeing that an object exists at `mainObject[obj.prop]`.

Alternatively, if you want a more concise way of doing this you could consider the lodash library which offers the [`.set()` method](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#set):

```
_.set(mainObject, obj.prop + '.' + obj.prop, obj.value);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. It did help!

Answer (score 1):

all you can do is push your upcoming object into an array and by using reduce method you can simply achieve your desired output

```
let mainObject = [obj1, obj2].reduce((result, obj) => {
    result[obj.prop] = result[obj.prop] || {};
    result[obj.prop][obj.key] = obj.value;
    return result;
}, {});
```